# Sort output of pd.describe by column data type

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to sort the output of pandas' `describe` method, first by the column data type and then if possible by column name... so that all the columns with dates show up together in one group, then another grouping with the ints, then the strings and so on. How can this be done?

This is as far as I've got, `sort_values` causes it to crash:

```
df.describe(include='all').sort_values(by=df.dtypes.astype(str)).transpose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working first sort by index by [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html), then by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and last change order by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'V':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4.,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1.,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df1 = df.describe(include='all')
c = df.dtypes.astype(str).sort_index().sort_values()
print (c)
B    float64
D    float64
C      int64
E      int64
F     object
V     object
dtype: object
```

---

```
df2 = df1.reindex(columns=c.index)
print (df2)
               B         D         C         E    F    V
count   6.000000  6.000000  6.000000  6.000000    6    6
unique       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    2    6
top          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    b    c
freq         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    3    1
mean    4.500000  2.833333  5.500000  4.833333  NaN  NaN
std     0.547723  2.714160  2.880972  2.483277  NaN  NaN
min     4.000000  0.000000  2.000000  2.000000  NaN  NaN
25%     4.000000  1.000000  3.250000  3.250000  NaN  NaN
50%     4.500000  2.000000  5.500000  4.500000  NaN  NaN
75%     5.000000  4.500000  7.750000  5.750000  NaN  NaN
max     5.000000  7.000000  9.000000  9.000000  NaN  NaN
```

Alternative solution create `DataFrame` by `Series` and sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns:

```
df1 = df.describe(include='all')
c1 = (df.dtypes.astype(str)
        .rename_axis('a')
        .reset_index(name='b')
        .sort_values(['b','a']))
print (c1)
  a        b
1  B  float64
3  D  float64
2  C    int64
4  E    int64
5  F   object
0  V   object

df2 = df1.reindex(columns=c1['a'])
print (df2)
a              B         D         C         E    F    V
count   6.000000  6.000000  6.000000  6.000000    6    6
unique       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    2    6
top          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    b    c
freq         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    3    1
mean    4.500000  2.833333  5.500000  4.833333  NaN  NaN
std     0.547723  2.714160  2.880972  2.483277  NaN  NaN
min     4.000000  0.000000  2.000000  2.000000  NaN  NaN
25%     4.000000  1.000000  3.250000  3.250000  NaN  NaN
50%     4.500000  2.000000  5.500000  4.500000  NaN  NaN
75%     5.000000  4.500000  7.750000  5.750000  NaN  NaN
max     5.000000  7.000000  9.000000  9.000000  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It's pretty close, but for some reason I don't get all column names to be sorted alphabetically inside each grouping

Comment: @RafaelSanchez - Added new solution, I think it should working correct.